# To open a new tab in Screen at your current location

Tags: gnu-screen

Let's assume that you are at `/users/cs/uni/databases/python/codes/` and you want to compare the outputs of the same command with different parameters.

The program asks you the outputs such that you would like to have two windows open at the same folder such that you can run simply `python code.py` at both windows for different parameters.

I would like to know how you open a new tab in Screen such that the location of the new tab is at the folder where you are at. If I open a new tab, the location of the tab is at my Home.

**How can you make a new tab open at the current folder in Screen?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just run `screen` inside screen and it'll open a new window in the current directory.

Comment: Ouch!! Who would have thought it could be THAT easy?

Comment: Very cool! What if we're running some long process and can't get to a prompt, though?

Comment: @orjac: Perhaps `^z`, `screen`, `fg` ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! - It was easier than I first thought.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do a `screen -dmS SessionName && screen -r SessionName` and I'm in my working dir not my Home dir.

Maybe you have some custom config file ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
screen -X chdir `pwd`; screen -X screen
```

This sets screen's (not your shell's) current directory to your shell's current directory and opens a new window.

You could also do

```
screen -X chdir `pwd`; screen -X screen; screen -X ~
```

This will additionally restore screen's current directory to your home directory.

Put that in an alias and you should be fine.